Is sleep apnea risk from larger neck dependent on composition?
A common risk factor of sleep apnea is stated as a large neck, of 43cm or more.
Neck size vital sign of increased risk of OSA
neck to height ratio can be a screening tool of OSA
Now you would think that strengthening the muscles in your neck would reduce the risk factor of sleep apnea. However doing so would increase the neck size. I have looked but haven't found any information regarding if the risk only increases if the size increase is due to fat. Or does muscle also pose a problem?
